# Yii Framework: Model Relations on a condition

Tags: activerecord, yii, model, relational, database-relations

I have a User, Profile, Teacher, and Student models. Database looks as follows:

[image]

In the `relations` function of my `Teacher` and `Student` models, I  would like to have:

```
'profile' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Profile', 'user_id', 'condition' => 'profile.user_id = 'teacher.user_id'),
```

Basically, I would like to write something that would output the same result as the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM teacher, profile WHERE teacher.user_id = profile.user_id
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM student, profile WHERE student.user_id = profile.user_id
```

Comment: And what is the problem? You can have the `condition` block there. It should work.

Comment: @Pentium10 The problem with this is the following: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teacher.user_id' in 'where clause'.`

Comment: You need to sort out the aliases you put there. If you are in your Teacher model, then the table alias is `t`, you should have `t.user_id`.

Comment: @Pentium10 Tried but returned `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.user_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Have you tried adding 'with'=>'teacher' to your relation? Your error about unknown 'teacher' column tells that there's no JOIN happening